# How to prove the product representation of **Baenes G-function**?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, gamma-function, infinite-product

How to prove the formula of **Barnes G-dunction**
$$G(z+1)=(2\pi)^{z/2}\text{exp}\left(-\frac{z(z+1)}{2}- \frac{\gamma z^{2}}{2}\right)\, \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)^{k}\text{exp}\left(\frac{z^2}{2k}-z\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to prove that the formula works, because the function is inherently defined by the formula.

All other relationships pertaining to the Barnes G-function are derived, coincide, or in agreement with this definition. At its heart there is no difference between $G(z+1)$ and the RHS of the product representation.

I suppose you could go backward from other relations to prove that the formula **is consistent**, but you can't prove it intrinsically- it is defined in this way.